# convertAndSend vs. SendTo annotaiton

Tags: java, spring

I have the following piece of code:

```
@Controller
@EnableScheduling
public class QuoteController {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
    @SendTo(value="/topic/quote")
    public String sendPrice() {
        return "message from scheduler";
    }
}
```

And it doesn't send the message to the channel. But the following code works:

```
@Controller
@EnableScheduling
public class QuoteController {
    @Autowired
    public SimpMessageSendingOperations messagingTemplate;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay=5000)
    public String sendPrice() {
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/quote", "message from scheduler");
    }
}
```

Comment: `@SendTo` works when the request is coming from the browser and interpreted by spring framework. And `convertAndSend` is the api you can use it in any environment. Because you are using it in Thread, this is not an endpoint in spring and value returned by the `sendPrice()` method will not be processed by spring.

Comment: I think @VikramSingh is sort of right, though I disagree with the reason: `@SendTo` works when the method being annotated is involved in messaging interactions - Spring invokes it in response to a message it received, and takes the `@SendTo` annotation as an indication that a reply message is to be generated.  Here, `sendPrice()` is invoked by Spring, but not in a messaging context, so Spring has no reason to think that a reply is expected - so the `@SendTo` annotation is ignored...

Comment: Yes I think when The method is annotated with `@SendTo` spring treat it as an messaging endpoint and when it receives a message from client it internally call `convertAndSend` method to send message to client. But In case of `@Scheduled` annotation it will be invoked sometime latter without receiving message from client. Because there is no client is involved it doesn't make sense to send message to client which might be not available at the time of the invocation.

Answer (score 0):

We should use `@SendTo` annotation only by functions that called by websocket, it's mean functions annocated with `@MessageMapping`.

If you want to send message to queue in other way you should use `messagingTemplate.convertAndSend`.

Example for `@SendTo`:

```
@MessageMapping("/hello") // from websocket
@SendTo("/topic/bla")
public String foo1(String message) {
    return message;
}
```

Example for `.convertAndSend`:

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

@GetMapping("/{msg}") //from GET request
public void foo2(@PathVariable String msg) {
    template.convertAndSend("/topic/bla", msg);
}
```